# how to import excel data and display in grid?

Tags: gxt

i am using **ExtGWT(gxt)**. i have a requirement where i need to import excel data and display the data in a grid. please help me how to achive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is two completely separate thing to do...

First you have the import of the excel file, you can put this directly on the grid as it will require being processed on server side. Likely into a database on the server.

A quick search found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excelxmllibrary.aspx) library to do just that

The GXT application can then retrieve this data and place it into a grid by retrieving a list of POJOs and converting to `BeanModel`'s for use in the `ListStore` of the grid

Best example of loading data into a Grid see explorer [here](http://extjs.com/examples/#beanmodelgrid).

This should get you started as I cannot be sure of specifics without more information of your set up.